# SSIS - Transfer SQL Server Objects Task - Problems with SMO Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS within Visual Studio 2012. I am planning to use the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task in SSIS to, well, transfer (nearly) all objects (schema only) between servers. I am unfortunately stuck at the SMO Connection Manager configuration step. While in the Editor for the task, I click on Source Connection and select <New Connection ...>. I then enter the name of the server I wish to use as the source. When clicking on Test Connection, I get a Failed to Server error message. I am able to connect to the server from SSMS, and I can make a successful connection if I create a Connection Manager in SSIS. I simply cannot successfully connect when using the SMO Connection Manager within the Transfer SQL Server Object Task.

Comment: Is there an error message or does it just time out?

Comment: The error message is ""Failed to connect to server.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurrred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and theat SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server Error: 2)"

Comment: I think the reason why you are seeing a difference in behavior between ssis and SSMS is that the connection type is OLEDB in SSMS and SMOServer in SSIS.  I'm not sure why the SMO connection type would fail or what the nuances to that are.  But rather than pursue this route, could you consider alternatives for syncing up schemas?  Is SSDT a possibility?

Comment: SSDT is a possibility, though others on my team have had troubles with SSDT when trying to transfer all objects. It was unclear what the problem was, however. I may check into SSDT today.

Comment: There are a handful of objects that are not supported in SSDT, but I haven't encountered any of them on any projects that I have worked on.  You might manage some of these issues with pre and post deployment scripts.  Let me know if you have questions on SSDT, I am an advocate of this development style.  I have always found the SMO tasks in SSIS to be a bit clunky and there certainly aren't going to handle diffs with schema changes over time.

Comment: That's what I'd heard and seen about SSDT in the past. I'll dig into it further today or earl next week. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 5):

It's probably already too late, but I've realized that if you don't click on Test Connection and leave the Server Name, you can click OK, and when you hit the dropdown on SourceDatabase, the list of DBs appear.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to enable TCP/IP protocol for instance (I was trying to connect to) in Sql Server Configuration Manager and in Properties of protocol on tab IP Addresses for IPAll set TCP Port to 1433.

Answer (score 0):

I have just came across the same issue one hour ago in VS2012. There is a bug related to Visual Studio, which gives you this error message regardless the network connection when you add `SMOServer` type of connection and press `Test Connection` button before pressing `OK` button.

Therefore, what you need to do is to add SMOServer Connection, select your source and press OK without testing the connection. Then you can test the connection after making a right click and edit on the connection manager. The test works when you do in that way.